# Project and assembly naming conventions

Tags: .net, naming-conventions

There is [Microsoft names of assemblies guideline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229048.aspx) but personally I don't like lengthy names in solution tree. When there are dozen of lengthy names it's hard to pick the project you want.

Do you keep project name same as assembly name or short it somehow?

For example if there is **MyCompany.MyProject.Dal.dll** assembly maybe it's more useful to name project simply **Dal** (but make it compilable into MyCompany.MyProject.Dal.dll) ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The project name (in common with the solution name) doesn't really matter to the *output*, as long as the project's "Assembly name:" and "Default namespace:" options are set correctly. So have fun, but I wouldn't take them *too* far from the namespace.

If your namespace is `FooCorp.MegaProject.DAL.dll`, then anyone with the project already *knows* they work for `FooCorp`, and they probably already have the project named *on disk* as `MegaProject`, so it probably isn't going to add much confusion to just have `DAL.csproj`, especially if this is in the path "...\FooCorp\MegaProject\DAL\DAL.csproj" or similar. I've certainly done this before (at my last job, where we had hundreds and hundreds of assemblies).